# An easy tutorial for a tool that supports text classification, clustering and topic modeling

Tags: weka, text-mining, gensim, topic-modeling, mallet

What is a text mining tool with some easy tutorials and active community? I found some popular but not sure which one to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest [TAToM](https://de.dariah.eu/tatom-intro) by Allan Riddell.

And there is a portal to more tutorials called  [TeLeMaCo](https://fedora.clarin-d.uni-saarland.de/hub/kwsearch/topic%20model/0/) at the CLARIN centre at Saarland University.